# PHP replace string with values from array

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I have a string such as:

```
   Hello <%First Name%> <%Last Name%> welcome
```

and I have a array

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [First Name] => John
        [Last Name] => Smith
    )
```

What I need to do is take the string and replace the words in <% with the actual text from the array

So my output would be

```
   Hello John Smith welcome
```

Im not sure how to accomplish this but I cant even seem to replace it with regular text

```
$test = str_replace("<%.*%>","test",$textData['text']);
```

Sorry I should of mentioned that the array keys may vary as well as the `<%First Name%>`

so it could even be `<%city%>` and the array can be `city=>New York`

Comment: You can't do regex in str_replace but you can in preg_replace

Comment: then use `array_keys()` and iterate through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
    $string ="Hello <%First Name%> <%Last Name%> welcome";
    preg_match_all('~<%(.*?)%>~s',$string,$datas);
    $Array = array('0' => array ('First Name' => 'John', 'Last Name' => 'Smith' ));
    $Html =$string;
    foreach($datas[1] as $value){           
        $Html =str_replace($value, $Array[0][$value], $Html);
    }
    echo str_replace(array("<%","%>"),'',$Html);
```

Answer (score 24):

```
$array = array('<%First Name%>' => 'John', '<%Last Name%>' => 'Smith');
$result = str_replace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $textData['text']);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use an array for both the search and replace variables in str_replace

```
$search = array('first_name', 'last_name');
$replace = array('John', 'Smith');

$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str_replace`

```
$replacedKeys = array('<%First Name%>','<%Last Name%>');

$values = array('John','Smith');

$result = str_replace($replacedKeys,$values,$textData['text']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "Hello <%First Name%> <%Last Name%> welcome";
$matches = array(
    'First Name' => 'John',
    'Last Name' => 'Smith'
);

$result = preg_replace_callback('/<%(.*?)%>/', function ($preg) use ($matches) { return isset($matches[$preg[1]]) ? $matches[$preg[1]] : $preg[0]; }, $string);            

echo $result;
// Hello John Smith welcome
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~<%(First|Last) Name)%>~', function ($m) {
    return $yourarray[$m[1] . ' Name']; } ,$str);
```

or much simple (and probably more efficient), use Brian H. answer (and replace search strings by `<%First Name%>` and `<%Last Name%>`).

Answer (score 1):

```
function temp_tag_replace($tag_start,$tag_end,$temp_array,$text){
      if(is_array($temp_array)){
      $keys=array_keys($temp_array);
        foreach ( $keys as $key){
        $val=$temp_array[$key];
        $key=$tag_start.$key.$tag_end;
        $text=str_replace($key,$val,$text);
        }
      }
      return $text;
    }

    $text='Hi %*Name*% %*Surname*%';
    $temp_array=array('Name'=>'Otto','Surname'=>'Man');
    $tag_start='%*';
    $tag_end='*%';

    echo temp_tag_replace($tag_start,$tag_end,$temp_array,$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ' Hello '.$array[0][First Name].' '.$array[0][Last Name].'  welcome';
```